# How can I create an .exe file of a code (using python) that need a variable file path to work?

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller

I’m new in IT field and I need some advice for how can I solve this problem, using python. It’s a volunteer work for a Non-Profit Organization.

My script is done, but in the code there is reference to specific file path that only will work in my PC. I need to convert the script to .exe (pyinstaller), but it won’t work in other PCs, because the path will create an error.

My code use data from a xlsx and it also use an image .png, and both files are referenced in the code with the path that they are saved in my PC. How can I convert to .exe in a way that the program still working in other PCs? I need a way to pack both files and the script in the .exe (in this case, what do I put to replace the path in my code for a reference to this "packed file"?) or insert a variable path instead the specific path related only with mt PC. What are the ways to solve that?

Edit:
In resume, I need that this line of code work in other PCs after I convert the .py to an .exe file, using for that the pyinstaller:

```
import pandas as pd
dados = pd.read_excel(r"/Users/lucas/Documents/UDV/NE/Dados.xlsx")
```

As the path is only related with my PC, if I try to convert to exe and open in other machine, it will result in a error message.

Thanks!
Obs: The .exe will be used for normal users, so I expected that in the final the person only will click on the .exe and it will do the job without hard commands by the user.

Comment: Okay... so do you expect the user to have a copy of this same file but in another location or do you want to compile the spreadsheet with your application? Or in other words is the .xlsx file something that will be edited by the user or is it a static document that the user never sees?

Comment: Yes, the user will have a copy of the xlsx file in another location, and it will be possible to edit the document.

Comment: Okay then you either need to implement some means of asking where their version of the file is, unless it is always located `Users/{username}/Documents/UDV/NE/Dados.xlslx`.  Is the same thing true for the image you mention or can that be compiled with the application?

Comment: So, instead of this line of code, I call a system window asking the user to chose where the xlsx is located and, using this answer, it's possible to extract the file location to use in the application?

I didn't search for a library with this functionality yet, but I think it's easier to find. But with someone could indicate a library that works well, it will be useful.

And in the case of the image, it can be compiled with the application, as you ask. How can I do that?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a library if you don't mind having your user type the location into a terminal.  otherwise you can use tkinter since it ships with python anyway and is pretty simple.  When I can I will answer your question with an example. If someone else doesn't get to it before me.

Comment: did you come up with a solution for getting the path to the file from the user?